# Access HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name as Parameter to SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net

Is is possible to access User.Identity.Name from an XML parameter in an SqlDataSource?

```
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SelectLoadScanner1" DefaultValue="0" Name="loadId" PropertyName="loadId" />
            <asp:SomeParameterType DefaultValue="" Name="username" PropertyName="HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

I would like the second parameter `SomeParameterType` to reference an `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

I know you can add an onInserting event and do it in the code behind, but I would rather it be in XML if possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot directly access this property by using standard [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.aspx). But you can add a new property `UserName` to your page/control and access it through `ControlParameter`:

```
public string UserName
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.User == null)
            return null;
        else
            return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

As another option you could extend the base `Parameter` class.

Comment: What would I use as the `ControlID` for this solution?

Comment: @jax: the `ID` of control which holds the `UserName` property.

Comment: So if I place this in the Page, what do I use?

Comment: @jax: if you set the `Page.ID` manually use that value, otherwise use `__Page` - it's default value.